# Pass itemized line items to paypal payflow pro

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

I'm using Drupal Commerce with commerce_payflow pro module. Everything works fine, but I'd like to be able to see shipping and line item details associated with the paypal orders. I'm accomplshing this in my paypal WPS module as follows:

```
$product_count = 1;
foreach ($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
  if (in_array($line_item_wrapper->type->value(), commerce_product_line_item_types())) {
    $data['item_name_' . $product_count] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->title->value();
    // Divide price by 100 to add decimal point.
    $data['amount_' . $product_count] = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_unit_price->amount->value() / 100;
    $data['quantity_' . $product_count] = round($line_item_wrapper->quantity->value(), 2);
    $product_count++;
  }
}
$order_total = field_get_items('commerce_order', $order, 'commerce_order_total');
$shipping_cost = $order_total[0]['data']['components'][1]['price']['amount'];
```

I need to do something quite similar with the commerce_payflow_pro module. 
I've looked through these docs: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/CA/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_Guide.pdf but can't find the proper NVP definitions that would allow me to pass line-items...

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Hi @starsinmypockets, I'm not able to help you with your issue but I would love to know how you did this with the paypal WPS module. Any chance you could point me in the right direction?